# Roo getting number instead of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, roo-gem

I am using roo to parse out an excel sheet like this

```
worksheet.parse(
        :partNo => "PM_PartNo",
        :salePartNo => "PM_SalesPartNo",
        :appSearchInclude => "PM_AppSearchInclude",
        :desc => "PM_WebApp_Description",
        :brand => "PM_Brand",
        :appSegment => "PM_ApplicationSegment",
        :group => "PM_ProductGroup",
        :design => "PM_ProductDesign",
        :material => "PM_Material",
        :line => "PM_ProdLine",
        :baseSeries => "PM_BaseSeries",
        :colorCode => "PM_ColorCode",
        :series => "PM_Series",
        :weightType => "PM_oz_gram",
        :appRim => "PM_ApplicationRim",
        :coating => "PM_Coating",
        :pcs => "PM_PCSconversion",
        :clean => true
    )  do |hash|
```

However, Roo keeps giving me a number 200275577.0 for the PM_PartNo column. In the excel sheet, this column has all cells formatted as text. What is should return in the parse is "200275577" as text, not 200275577.0 as a number. Is there a way to ensure it adheres to the excel formatting?

Comment: Are you entering it as `200275577` or `"200275577.0"`?

Comment: It is entered as 200275577 in excel with the cell format as text.

Comment: Not ideal, but could you just do `my_var.to_s`?

Comment: @JustinWood That seems to work. Is there no way to indicate this in the parse or some way more global so that I don't have to to_s every instance of the used hash?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use this gem for anything. Best option may be to [post a ticket](https://github.com/Empact/roo/issues) if this is not behaving the way you believe it should be.

Comment: change cell format as general or number and adjust decimal to check.

Comment: @ZAT Cell format is listed as text in excel, which should return the value as is. The issue isn't with the excel format, it's with the roo GEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/Empact/roo/issues/139) with roo.  There is a general workaround contributed by a user in the issue, or you can just convert the value yourself with `.to_i.to_s`.

Comment: I imagine there will be issues with leading 0s. 0000505 would be 505.0 which .to_i.to_s would convert to 505. Untested, but worth a caution.

Comment: https://github.com/Empact/roo/issues/86 For reference. The issue seems to be with the Spreedsheet GEM as well, a requirement of Roo.

Comment: Very true, you may need to use `rjust` to preserve leading zeros

Comment: searching on the docs, there doesn't seem to be an option to specify that you want to get the values in `text`, as they appear in the cells. Is there an `option` to do this with [`Roo::Excelx#parse`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/roo/2.8.3/Roo/Base#parse-instance_method)? or you still need `to_s` the values of each row?